# Rest API mocking with wiremock - json

Tags: json, filenames, wiremock

wiremock stub : curl to json generation

I am trying to set up a wiremock stub

```
curl -X 'PUT’ \ 'https://ip/upload/file’ \ -H 'accept: application/json’ \ -H 'authorization: sso-auth' \ -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data’ \ -F 'job_file=@upload.txt;type=text/plain’
```

Just wanted to create a json file for the above request in the mapping folder of wiremock.
-F indicates the file to be uploaded, the filename is upload.txt.
Please suggest json format for the above.

Above is the primary requirement. Secondary requirement is a way to extract the filename from the incoming request and see whether the file is already present in the local path and set a status internally, so that if we post a status request post this one, it will give a response based on the flag set previously for the file availability

Comment: What issue are you running into trying to accomplish your requirements?

Comment: Mainly how to transform the section " -F 'job_file=@upload.txt;type=text/plain " into the corresponding wiremock json mapping .

Comment: What are you trying to transform? Can you give an example JSON response?

Comment: {
        "request": {
                "method": "PUT",
                "url": "/ip/upload/file/ip/upload/file"
        },
        "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "body": "Success"
        }
} , just a normal success response like the one above will do , but need to find a way to send the -F filename  part (ie the filename to be uploaded ) in the above json